# Inputbox prevent user from pressing enter when value is blank

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I have the following code :
`Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1).Value = InputBox("INTRODUCE ACT JUSTIFICATIV")`
User must enter letters in inputbox

I want to prevent the user from accidentally pressing enter if value in inputbox is blank with a personalized error message.

And pressing  cancel button to exit sub.

Comment: Try creating a `UserForm` to do that instead of **InputBox**. You can customise it to do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Users input to a variable and then test to see whether it is valid or not.

```
Dim usrInput as String

Do
    usrInput = InputBox("INTRODUCE ACT JUSTIFICATIV")

    If usrInput = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Your Error Message"
    End If
Loop While usrInput = vbNullString
```

Comment: is it possible to loop until user enters non blank value?

Comment: @Tom This loops until the user enters a non-blank input. To be able to handle presses of cancel buttons I suggest using `Application.InputBox` which returns a `Variant`. It returns `False` if the user presses the cancel or x button.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Sub testInputBoxValidate()
  Dim strInpB As String
  strInpB = InputBox("INTRODUCE ACT JUSTIFICATIV")
  If strInpB = "" Then MsgBox "You did not introduce anything!": Exit Sub
  Range("P" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strInpB
End Sub
```

And a variant to oblige the user inputting something:

```
Sub testInputBoxValidate()
  Dim strInpB As String
Start:
  strInpB = InputBox("INTRODUCE ACT JUSTIFICATIV")
  If strInpB = "" Then MsgBox "You did not introduce anything!": GoTo Start
  Range("P" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strInpB
End Sub
```

I would also suggest you to try some more other checking. For instance, that 'ACT JUSTIFICATIV' must not have a specific length (number of digits)? A specific pattern like `xxxx###', where '###' is a three (x) digits number?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.InputBox` which gives you a little more control. The user will be prompted until they either enter a non-blank string or press the cancel or x buttons

```
Dim vInput As Variant: vInput = ""
Do
    vInput = Application.InputBox("INTRODUCE ACT JUSTIFICATIV", Type:=2) '2 -> String type
    If vInput = False Then 'User pressed Cancel or x button
        Exit Do
    ElseIf Len(vInput) > 0 Then 'User has entered non-blank value
        Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = vInput
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can force the `InputBox` to close only if something was entered. Instead, read the result into variable and loop until something valid was entered

```
Dim answer as string, okay As Boolean
answer = ""
okay = False
Do While Not okay
    answer = InputBox("INTRODUCE ACT JUSTIFICATIV")
    On Error Resume Next
    okay = Range(answer & "1").Address <> ""
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop
```

Now, the InputBox will pop up until a valid column was entered.